# Can I use a calculated column to show whether a vehicle check submission has already been completed on any given day

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, powerapp

I am creating a list which will be used for daily forklift checks that need to be completed via a power app. What I would like is a column that can calculate whether there has already been a check form completed in the day so there is no need for a second.

For example I check the forklift in the morning and complete the form. Someone else gets on the forklift in the afternoon and when they scan the QR code in the vehicle to bring up the check form the "status" column can be shown which should show that the check has already been completed today.

Hopefully that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible using SharePoint calculated columns.

Calculated columns has below limitations:

> - You cannot reference a value in a **row other than the current row**.
> - You cannot reference a value in another list or library.

**Documentation**: [Introduction to SharePoint formulas and functions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/introduction-to-sharepoint-formulas-and-functions-94e1b4cc-cd1c-49c2-80ec-90c9b9591f47)

You will have to write custom logic as per your requirements inside Power Apps only.

Comment: Okay thank you. Do you have some advice for the best place to start with the custom logic I may need?

Comment: Doc for barcode scanner: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/controls/control-new-barcode-scanner. Based on barcode value you can check if same value is available in existing list items or not. You can use [Filter()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-filter-lookup) for this. If you found matching item, you can show item details using other control in power apps like label/text input.